# "Make sure you are not dividing by zero" error Visual Basic express

Tags: vb.net

I am using Visual Basic express 2010.I want to create a programm that is asking for number and stops when 0 is given.Then I want to check all that values to find the minimum value the maximum value the average and the sum.I have that code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim total As Integer
        total = 0
        Dim average As Integer
        average = 0
        Dim loops As Integer
        loops = 0
        Dim max As Integer
        max = 0
        Dim min As Integer
        min = Val(InputBox("Give me the first number"))
        Dim number As Integer
        number = Val(InputBox("Give me a number"))
        Do Until number = 0
            loops = loops + 1
            If number < min Then
                min = number
            ElseIf number > max Then
                max = number
            End If
            total = number + total

        Loop
        average = total / loops
        MsgBox(total)
    End Sub
End Class
```

When i hit F5 it brings up the screen.After the first 2 inputboxes the program crashes.Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: `number` is not changing in the loop, so eventually the value of `loops` will be too larger (Overflow).  Not sure what it has to do with Divide by Zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey take a look at this code.You had the problem because the number was not changing.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim total As Integer
        total = 0
        Dim average As Integer
        average = 0
        Dim loops As Integer
        loops = 0
        Dim max As Integer
        max = 0
        Dim min As Integer
        min = Val(InputBox("Give me the first number"))
        Dim number As Integer
        number = Val(InputBox("Give me a number"))
        Do Until number = 0
            loops = loops + 1
            If number < min Then
                min = number
            ElseIf number > max Then
                max = number
            End If
            total = number + total
            number = Val(InputBox("Give me a number"))
        Loop
        average = total / loops
        MsgBox(total)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your loop:

```
Do Until number = 0
    loops = loops + 1
    If number < min Then
        min = number
    ElseIf number > max Then
        max = number
    End If
    total = number + total
Loop
```

It will continue until `number` is 0, but `number` is never modified.  So if it's not already 0, it will *never* be 0.  Thus, the loop continues indefinitely.  In that loop you do this:

```
loops = loops + 1
```

Since `loops` is an `Integer`, it has a fairly finite range.  Once it reaches the value of `MaxInt`, you can't add to it anymore.  So the next time you add to it, you see an exception.

You'll need to modify `number` in the loop in order for it to ever finish.

Note that the "divide by zero" part isn't actually part of the error message you're seeing.  It's just a suggestion that Visual Studio is showing you, since dividing by zero is a common source of this error.  It's just not the source of the error this time.